# What is the idiomatic way to share variables between different patterns of the same function?

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to get a decent handle on writing code in haskell, and I've noticed a pattern of error that I've committed a few times:

```hs
doFoo :: ...
doFoo pattern1 = fooHelper ...
doFoo pattern2 = fooHelper ...
  where
    fooHelper = ...
```

`fooHelper` is of course not in scope for `doFoo pattern1`. I've found myself correcting the error by using a single irrefutable pattern for `doFoo` and then pattern matching on it using a case expression inside the function:

```hs
doFoo :: ...
doFoo irrefutable = case irrefutable of
  pattern1 -> fooHelper ...
  pattern2 -> fooHelper ...
  where
    fooHelper = ...
```

`fooHelper` is now of course in scope for both patterns.

As far as I know, pattern matching at the function level is in every way equivalent to pattern matching in case expressions (though please correct me if I'm wrong), so this seems a reasonable thing to do. Would this pattern be considered idiomatic, or is there a better (or just commonly used alternative) way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's common to convert it into an case expression in this case. In addition to that, with [`LambdaCase` extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/lambda_case.html), you can make it a little bit shorter.

```
doFoo :: ...
doFoo = \case
  pattern1 -> fooHelper ...
  pattern2 -> fooHelper ...
  where
    fooHelper = ...
```

As of GHC 9.4.1, you can even pattern match on multiple parameters. So, for example, you can write something like this:

```
doFoo :: ...
doFoo = \cases
  pattern1 pattern1' -> fooHelper ...
  pattern2 pattern2' -> fooHelper ...
  where
    fooHelper = ...
```

instead of writing

```
doFoo :: ...
doFoo x y = case (x, y) of
  (pattern1, pattern1') -> fooHelper ...
  (pattern2, pattern2') -> fooHelper ...
  where
    fooHelper = ...
```

Note that it's `\cases`, not `\case`

Comment: I'm trying to experiment with `\cases` on `9.4.2`. Strangely, the [example from the proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0302-cases.rst#example) is not working for me. I have `LambdaCase` and `BlockArguments` enabled. The error is on the second line of the example and reads "parse error on input ‘|’" referring to `p (x:xs) | p x`. Can you help me understand where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I tried it on GHC 9.4.2, and it worked. I think it's an indentation issue because I got your error when I added an extra indentation to the second line.

Comment: If I copy the example verbatim, `ghc` complains with the error above. However, I was able to get it to work by moving `_ [] -> []` to the next line at the same indent. I don't see why the original formatting would have been invalid, however. This kind of feels like a bug. Also. `hls` complains even when `ghc` accepts the code as valid, which is definitely a bug. I'll file an issue.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest indenting the `where` less than the `case` clauses. Regardless of what the compiler thinks about it, indentation should also make it clear to a human reader that the `where` scope goes over all the clauses.